# Python Webscraping - BeautifulSoup Attribute Error

Tags: python, web

Trying to learn about webscraping and currently working on scraping the team stats data off the nfl website for a specific team(chiefs).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

data = requests.get('http://www.nfl.com/teams/kansascitychiefs/statistics? 
team=KC')

#parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

main = soup.find('div',{'id':'team-stats-wrapper'})
teamstats = soup.find('table',{'id':'data-table1'})
for tbody in teamstats.find('tbody'):
    print(tbody)
```

the main and teamstats variables are just specifying what part of the html code I want to use from the website as you all know.

I'm getting the attribute error in the for statement, saying "File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is no attribute called 'tbody'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute called `tbody` here. If you want to print the whole table. This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('http://www.nfl.com/teams/kansascitychiefs/statistics?team=KC')

#parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

main = soup.find('div',{'id':'team-stats-wrapper'})
teamstats_table= main.find('table',{'class':'data-table1 '})
print(teamstats_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

data = requests.get('http://www.nfl.com/teams/kansascitychiefs/statistics? 
team=KC')

#parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

main = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'team-stats-wrapper'})
teamstats = soup.find_all('table',{'id':'data-table1'})
for tbody in teamstats.find('tbody'):
    print(tbody)
```